# How to use MaxPooling1D with Conv1D

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I use Conv1D like this

```
X_train_t = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1,12)
X_test_t = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1,12)

print(X_train_t.shape)
print(X_train_t)

K.clear_session()
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(12,1, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,12)))

#model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = (6))) 

model.add(LSTM(3))

model.add(Dense(1))
```

I add maxpooling to improve performance like this under line model.add(Conv1D..

```
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = (6)))
```

but it show error like this

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 6 from 1 for 'max_pooling1d_1/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,1,1,12].
```

It work if I set pool_size = (1) but it increase more loss value. If I want to change pool_size to another value not 1. How to edit model ?

Answer (score 2):

[MaxPooling1D](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/) needs a 3d Tensor for its inputs with shape: `(batch_size, steps, features)`. Based on your code, `X_train_t` and `X_test_t` have 1 step (`*.shape[0], 1, 12`). When Pooling moves its window 6 steps (`pool_size=(6)`) it can't. As a result it throws such an exception.

**Suggestion**: Try to change your input shape

**Minimal example**: Here is the one possible solution with `Conv1D`:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(input_dim=1000, output_dim=128, input_shape=(12,))
    model.add(Convolution1D(filters=2, kernel_size=100, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=6))
    model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
    model.add(Dense(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a Dense layer and Reshape Layer to overcome this issue.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(12,1, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,12)))
model.add(Dense(32*3))
model.add(Reshape((3,32)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = (3))) 
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(1))
```